# How to pass map in Terraform to a manifest yaml file using templatefile function to set NodeSelector?

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, terraform-template-file

I have a manifest yaml file in Terraform to deploy a deployment on a Kubernetes cluster and I want to pass a map having key-value pairs defining node selectors to that yaml file using templatefile function to set `nodeSelector` on it.

This is how my Terraform code looks like:

```
...
resource "kubernetes_manifest" "deployment" {
  manifest = yamldecode(
    templatefile("${path.module}/resources/deployment-tmpl.yaml",
      {
        app_name      = var.app_name,
        app_namespace = var.app_namespace
    })
  )
}
...
```

This is how my manifest yaml code looks like:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ${app_name}
  name: ${app_name}
  namespace: ${app_namespace}
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/name: ${app_name}
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/name: ${app_name}
    spec:
      containers:
        ...
...
```

My node selector variable may look like this:

```yaml
variable "node_selector" {
  default = {
    "eks.amazonaws.com/nodegroup" = "app"
  }
}
```

My Terraform version is `v0.14.11`.

How can I do that in my case? I don't want to hardcode and I want to send a map which can have one or more key-value pairs.

Comment: Are you actually using Helm here?  The examples you show seem like they're using Terraform's templating language in combination with a `kubernetes_resource`, but neither part of that is Helm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to do so using `yamlencode` inside `templatefile` function in Terraform in this case.

I have changed the manifest yaml file as follows:

```yaml
...
    spec:
      nodeSelector:
        ${node_selector}
      containers:
...
```

I have changed the Terraform file as follows:

```
...
resource "kubernetes_manifest" "deployment" {
  manifest = yamldecode(
    templatefile("${path.module}/resources/deployment-tmpl.yaml",
      {
        app_name      = var.app_name,
        app_namespace = var.app_namespace,
        node_selector = yamlencode(var.node_selector)
    })
  )
}
...
```

Node selector variable will remain the same and can have more than one key-value pair:

```yaml
variable "node_selector" {
  default = {
    "eks.amazonaws.com/nodegroup" = "app"
  }
}
```

Reference: [Terraform - templatefile Function](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/templatefile)